# Makefile:6: recipe for target ‘all’ failed Products Support DragonBoard410c

Tags: c, linux

```
    I flashed Linaro on Snapdragon board and tried to execute the make but it was failed with following error msg. But it is working fine in the ubuntu.

                make -C /lib/modules/4.0.0-linaro-lt-qcom/build M=/home/linaro/Downloads modules
                make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-linaro-lt-qcom'
                CC [M] /home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.o
                /home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.c:90:12: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
                .write = writeToLCD,
                ^
                /home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.c:90:12: warning: (near initialization for ‘fops.write’)
                /home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.c:81:16: warning: ‘lcd_read’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
                static ssize_t lcd_read(struct file , char *, size_t, loff_t *); / reading data from lcd */
                ^
                /home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.c:82:16: warning: ‘lcd_write’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
                static ssize_t lcd_write(struct file , const char *, size_t, loff_t *);/ write data to lcd */
                ^
                scripts/basic/fixdep: 1: scripts/basic/fixdep: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
                scripts/Makefile.build:264: recipe for target '/home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.o' failed
                make[2]: *** [/home/linaro/Downloads/lcd.o] Error 2
                Makefile:1390: recipe for target 'module/home/linaro/Downloads' failed
                make[1]: *** [_module_/home/linaro/Downloads] Error 2
                make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-linaro-lt-qcom'
                Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
                make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The image we flashed on snapdragon board is linaro information regarding this we fount on 96boards.com
http://www.96boards.org/blog/part-1-home-surveillance-project-96boards/

This is the makefile is written for the lcd.c driver code. below lcd.c code is available could you please see that code and help me to resolve this problem.

```
obj-m:=lcd.o
    KDIR:=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD:=$(shell pwd)
    all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
        @rm -f Module.symvers app



        This is lcd.c driver code when i want to execute make it is not working properly it is giving the error which is mentioned above.
    here i am using the Grove lcd RGB backlight. the below link is lcd link
    https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Serial-LCD-p-773.html.And if i m directly trying to insert the .ko file which generated on other system it is giving the insmod failed could not insert module & invalid module format.



            /* Header files */
            #include <linux/module.h>       /* module_init,module_exit */
            #include <linux/fs.h>               /* struct file_operations */
            #include <linux/cdev.h>         /* cdev_alloc,cdev_add */
            #include <linux/device.h>       /* device_create,class_create */
            #include <linux/slab.h>             /* for kmalloc,kfree */
            #include <linux/uaccess.h>
            #include <linux/gfp.h>          /* for kmalloc function */

            /*Project specific include files*/
            #include <linux/i2c.h>          /* for I2c */
            #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>      /* for I2C */

            /* Macros */
            #define FIRST_MINOR 10      /* first minor number */
            #define NR_DEVS     1           /* Number of device numbers */

            /*new*/
            #define LCD_SLAVE       0x3E
            #define BUS         0x00
            #define REG_MODE1       0x00
            #define REG_MODE2       0x01
            #define REG_OUTPUT      0x08

            //commands
            #define LCD_CLEARDISPLAY    0x01
            #define LCD_RETURNHOME      0x02
            #define LCD_ENTRYMODESET    0x04
            #define LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL  0x08
            #define LCD_CURSORSHIFT     0x10
            #define LCD_FUNCTIONSET     0x20
            #define LCD_SETCGRAMADDR    0x40
            #define LCD_SETDDRAMADDR    0x80

            //display entry mode
            #define LCD_ENTRYRIGHT      0x00
            #define LCD_ENTRYLEFT       0x02
            #define LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT 0x01
            #define LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT 0x00

            //display on/off control
            #define LCD_DISPLAYON       0x04
            #define LCD_DISPLAYOFF      0x00
            #define LCD_CURSORON        0x02
            #define LCD_CURSOROFF       0x00
            #define LCD_BLINKON     0x01
            #define LCD_BLINKOFF        0x00

            // flags for display/cursor shift
            #define LCD_DISPLAYMOVE     0x08
            #define LCD_CURSORMOVE      0x00
            #define LCD_MOVERIGHT       0x04
            #define LCD_MOVELEFT        0x00

            // flags for function set
            #define LCD_8BITMODE        0x10
            #define LCD_2LINE       0x08

            //variables 
            char * lcd_text_; //variable to store user space lcd_text data

            //function definitions
            s32 writeByteRegister(struct i2c_client *client,u8 reg, u8 value);
            void clearLCD(struct i2c_client *client);
            void writeToLCD(struct i2c_client *client, const char *c);
            void initLCD(struct i2c_client *client);
            size_t write(struct file *, const char *buf, size_t c);


            /* Function Declarations for syscall definitions */
            int lcd_Open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filep);
            int lcd_Release(struct inode *in, struct file *fp);
            static ssize_t lcd_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *); /* reading data from lcd */
            static ssize_t lcd_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);/* write data to lcd */
            struct i2c_msg msg[1];         /* structure for each message */
            struct i2c_msg msg1[1];        /* structure for each message */
            struct i2c_client client1;

            /* @file_operations - Operations which can be performed with the device */   
            struct file_operations fops = {
                    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
                    .write = writeToLCD,
            };


            /* function declarations of i2c_driver */
            static int lcd_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id);
            static int lcd_remove(struct i2c_client *client);

            /* list of devices supported by my driver */
            static struct i2c_device_id lcd_id[] = {
                    { "lcd_i2c", 0 },
            };

            static struct i2c_driver lcd_driver = {
                    .driver.name    = "lcd_i2c",
                    .probe          = lcd_probe,
                    .remove         = lcd_remove,
                    .id_table       = lcd_id,
            };

            /* 
             * lcd_probe - probe function of driver
             * @client - pointer to structure client which has the address, algorithm followed by the device
             * @id - pointer to structure i2c_device which is maintained for the driver module
             *
             * Description - getting the address of the lcd device connected
             *
             * return value - 0 
             */

            static int lcd_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
            {
                            printk(KERN_ALERT "In probe function\n");
                    client1.addr = client->addr;
                    client1.adapter = client->adapter;
                    initLCD(&client1);
                    writeToLCD(&client1,"nice!");

                    return 0;
            }

            s32 writeByteRegister(struct i2c_client *client,u8 reg, u8 value)
            {
                s32 res = -1;
                res = i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(client, reg, value);

                if (res < 0)
                {
                    /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
                    //printk("%s: Error reading reg: 0x%x, code:%d \n",TAG,reg,res);
                }
                return res;
            }


            void clearLCD(struct i2c_client *client)
            {
                writeByteRegister(client, 0x00, LCD_CLEARDISPLAY );
            }

       /*   size_t write(struct file *, const char *buf, size_t c)
            {
                writeToLCD(&client1, buf);
            } 
        */
            void writeToLCD(struct i2c_client *client, const char *c)
            {

                int ascii_val=0;
                int i;
                for(i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    ascii_val = (int)c[i];              
                    writeByteRegister(client, 0x40, ascii_val);
                }
            }

            void initLCD(struct i2c_client *client)
            {

                writeByteRegister(client, 0x00, LCD_FUNCTIONSET | LCD_2LINE );
                //msleep(10);
                writeByteRegister(client, 0x00,LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | LCD_DISPLAYON 
                                    | LCD_CURSORON | LCD_BLINKON );
                //msleep(10);
                writeByteRegister(client, 0x00, LCD_CLEARDISPLAY );
                //msleep(40);
                writeByteRegister(client, 0x00,LCD_ENTRYMODESET | LCD_ENTRYLEFT 
                                    | LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT );

            }


            /* 
             * lcd_remove - remove function of driver 
             * @client - pointer to structure client which has the address, algorithm followed by the device
             *
             * return value - 0
             */

            static int lcd_remove(struct i2c_client *client)
            {
                    printk(KERN_ALERT "In remove function\n");
                    return 0;
            }

            /* Global variables */
            char *devname;        /* contains device name */
            int majNo;        /* holds major number */
            static dev_t lcd_dev;  /* encodes major number and minor number */
            struct cdev *lcd_cdev; /* holds character device driver descriptor */
            static int val;           /* for i2c_driver structure probe */

            /* To accept input from the command line */
            module_param(devname, charp, 0);

            /* class and device structures */
            static struct class *lcd_char_class;
            static struct device *lcd_char_device;


            /* 
             * myRelease - close function of the pseudo driver 
             * @in - pointer to structure inode
             * @fp - pointer to structure file
             *
             * return value - 0 
             */

            int lcd_Release(struct inode *in, struct file *fp)
            {
                    printk(KERN_INFO "File released \n");
                    return 0;
            }

            /*
             * myinit - init function of the kernel module
             *
             * Description - registering the driver 
             * return value - 0
             */

            static int __init lcd_init(void)
            {
                    int status;  /* checking the return value for alloc_chrdev_region */
                    int ret = 0; /* checking error values */

                    /* Allocating Device Numbers */
                    status = alloc_chrdev_region(&lcd_dev, FIRST_MINOR, NR_DEVS, devname);
                    if (status < 0) {
                            printk(KERN_NOTICE "Device numbers allocation failed: %d \n", status);
                            goto err;
                    }

                    printk(KERN_INFO "Major number allocated = %d \n", MAJOR(lcd_dev));
                    lcd_cdev = cdev_alloc();    /* Allocate memory for my_cdev */
                    if (lcd_cdev == NULL ) {
                            printk(KERN_ERR "cdev_alloc failed \n");
                            goto err_cdev_alloc;
                    }

                    cdev_init(lcd_cdev, &fops);     /* Initialize my_cdev with fops */
                    lcd_cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;

                    status = cdev_add(lcd_cdev, lcd_dev, NR_DEVS);  /* Add my_cdev to the list */
                    if (status) {
                            printk(KERN_ERR "cdev_add failed \n");
                            goto err_cdev_add;
                    }

                    /* Create a class and an entry in sysfs */
                    lcd_char_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, devname);
                    if (IS_ERR(lcd_char_class)) {
                            printk(KERN_ERR "class_create() failed \n");
                            goto err_class_create;
                    }

                    /* create mychar_device ni sysfs and an device entry will be made in /dev directory */

                    lcd_char_device = device_create(lcd_char_class, NULL, lcd_dev, NULL, devname);
                    if (IS_ERR(lcd_char_device)) {
                            printk(KERN_ERR "device_create() failed \n");
                            goto err_device_create;
                    }

                    val = i2c_add_driver(&lcd_driver);
                    if (val) {
                            printk("Registering I2C driver failed, errno is %d\n", val);

                err_device_create:
                            class_destroy(lcd_char_class);

                err_class_create:
                            cdev_del(lcd_cdev);

                err_cdev_add:
                            kfree(lcd_cdev);

                err_cdev_alloc:
                            unregister_chrdev_region(lcd_dev, NR_DEVS);
                err:
                            return ret;
                    }

                    return 0;
            }


            /*
             * myexit - cleanup function of the kernel module
             * 
             * Description - unregister the driver
             */

            static void __exit lcd_exit(void)
            {
                    printk(KERN_INFO "exiting the character Driver \n");

                    device_destroy(lcd_char_class, lcd_dev);
                    class_destroy(lcd_char_class);
                    cdev_del(lcd_cdev);
                    unregister_chrdev_region(lcd_dev, NR_DEVS);
                    i2c_del_driver(&lcd_driver);

                    return ;

            }

            module_init(lcd_init);
            module_exit(lcd_exit);

            MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Did you bother to read the error ? `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. You have added an unnecessary `(`

Comment: but we are not getting the same error in ubuntu & it is working fine

Comment: Are you executing this on your `x86` machine? Then you need at least a *cross compiler*, snapdragon is `arm`.

Comment: when we are executing on x86 machine it is working fine but when we are working on snapdragon 410c board we are getting this kind of error could u please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: strongly suggest you read this page from snapdragon: [setupNotes](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/sdllvm/readme-snapdragon-llvm.pdf)

Comment: Without the listing of the 'make file', the listing of the 'LCD.c' and the listing of the 'scripts/basic/fixdep' it will be very difficult for us to assist you.

Comment: I have added the lcd.c ,Makefile  & that fixdep file is not in readable format